# Validation of XML against a DTD in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, validation, dtd

I'm adapting a vcard implementation to a JS MVC framework. I'd like to be able to validate against the vcard spec's DTD in the client-side model. I've been been hunting around unsuccessfully for validation against a DTD Javascript. Anyone heard of something like this?

Comment: Found an old post in some forum. See if it helps [link](http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/86164-validating-xml-file-against-xml-schema-using-javascript.html)

Comment: I have managed to find this thing: [jssaxparser](https://code.google.com/p/jssaxparser/).  It claims to have some support for DTDs.

Comment: @Ravi yeah, I've seen some examples utilizing ActiveX, but we can't use ActiveX.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Well the jssaxparser thing is huge and seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you need to re-validate it on the server anyway?

Depending on DTD complexity, you may want to *only* check XML validity on the client (by attempting to deserialize it etc.), maybe throw in a couple primitive checks manually. It could then be fully validated on the server.

Anyway: [Validating XML Documents by Using DTDs](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=202) looks promising.

Comment: "Validating XML Documents by Using DTDs" uses ActiveX